# Can I use my original GPG key even though I've re-installed Linux?

Tags: debian, gpg

I'm a Debian user. I just created my own GPG public key. I'm just wondering if I re-install Linux on my system, is it possible to use the original GPG key or do I have to create a new one?

**NOTE:** If you know any good example sites for using the GPG key, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the file `~/.gnupg/random_seed`. Then make a backup of the whole directory `~/.gnupg/`. Copy it back after reinstalling the OS.

Take care to securely erase the files on the backup storage if other people might get access to it (e.g. if it's a USB stick).

Usually `/home` is put on a separate volume so that the user data is not affected by an OS change.

Comment: How do you securely erase a USB stick? It'd be better to store it on an encrypted filesystem.

Comment: @Hauke Laging, When I visit some blog site, then I saw the GPG key. Is there any reason to show their own GPG key to people ?

Comment: @Changju.rhee You obviously have to read some very basic stuff about asymmetric crypto. https://emailselfdefense.fsf.org/en/